# MPI derived type from a struct

Tags: mpi, derived-types

I have to transfer a number of elements of type:
    `typedef struct
    {
    float w;
    int a, b;
    } edge;`
to different processes, hence I am creating an MPI derived type like this:

```
unsigned int typecount;
MPI_Datatype PEDGE, types[2] = { MPI_FLOAT, MPI_INT };
MPI_Aint offsets[2], extent;
int blocklen[2] = { 1, 2 };

typecount     = 2;
offsets[0]    = 0;
MPI_Type_extent(MPI_FLOAT, &extent);
offsets[1]    = (1*extent);
MPI_Type_struct (typecount, blocklen, offsets, types, &PEDGE);
MPI_Type_commit(&PEDGE);
```

When I do a `sizeof(edge)` I get 12 bytes, but I am getting only 8 bytes when I do `sizeof(PEDGE)`...why is that? Apart from this, my code for sending some elements of PEDGE type to arrays of `edge` type are failing, probably because of this mismatch.

Comment: I've never used MPI derived types, but shouldn't you have `MPI_Datatype PEDGE, types[3] = { MPI_FLOAT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT };`? You have a `struct` with a float and two integers. Likewise your offsets would need a 3rd component. This would account for the 4 missing bytes (`sizeof(int)` is typically 4)

Comment: @tpg2114: That is what the `blocklen` array is for. See the reference on [`MPI_Type_struct()`](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node79.html#SECTION00436000000000000000).

Comment: I think if I just specify the number of unique datatypes, it should still work. I am mentioning the datatypes (MPI_FLOAT, MPI_INT), and the frequency of the specific datatypes (in blocklen), which should be enough for MPI to create the datatype. As "suszterpatt" said, since `sizeof` is a compile time operator, it fails to tell the exact size. But even using 3 elements, sizeof gives 8 bytes, so perhaps the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Sayan No, the problem is that `edge` and `PEDGE` are not the same type, so they do not have the same size.  Say you had a `struct` and a pointer to it.  The size of the pointer is clearly different from the size of the struct.  This is what `PEDGE` is: a handle to some internal MPI structure describing the datatype.  Taking its `sizeof` is meaningless.

Comment: "the problem is that edge and PEDGE are not the same type, so they do not have the same size" - I understand now, thank you for correcting

Comment: There can also be padding inside structs, so `a` does not necessarily start at `extent` as calculated.  The easiest way to deal with this is to use `offsetof` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point. May be you could you consider writing an answer from the comments.

Comment: Note that `MPI_Type_struct` has been deprecated in MPI-2.0 in favour of `MPI_Type_create_struct` and _removed_ in MPI-3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that an `MPI_Datatype` object such as `PEDGE` is not itself the new datatype, merely an opaque handle to some implementation-specific entity that MPI can interpret as a datatype. As such, `sizeof()` will not be able to return its accurate size. Use `MPI_Type_size()` instead.

As for the sends failing, I can't say much without seeing your code, but your datatype definition does look correct.

Comment: Or in other words, "ceci n'est pas un type".   PEDGE is a representation of a datatype, not the datatype itself.